# AirPlay button in multitasking bar?

Tags: iphone, mac, airplay

I don't have an Apple TV, so I've never had an AirPlay button anywhere. However I noticed while switching apps in a call that the AirPlay button appears while making a call. Pressing it does nothing. Also when the call in on speaker the AirPlay button goes blue (and still does nothing on pressing it) Why has it suddenly appeared, whats it's use during a call?

Also I then discovered a program for Mac which allows you to [AirPlay to a Mac](http://ericasadun.com/ftp/Macintosh/), increasing the AirPlay functionality vastly. And tryed pressing the button when I had that working, it still did nothing. (though the Mac program works as I can send youtube videos and photos to it)  And in the photos app, opening the multitasking bar and pressing the AirPlay button does nothing. So what is it there for anyway?

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of this icon? I'm not sure there is an airplay icon in my taskbar and I'm running 4.2.1. Hold down the power and home button at the same time to save a screen shot in your photos app.

Comment: It only appears when there's an airplay device on the network or if I'm in a call. I'll upload a screenshot now.

Comment: Actually there's one here already:http://ipadtreat.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/ios-42-multitasking-2.jpg

Comment: Wow. That's the airplay button alright! I've never seen it when I'm in an AppleTv'd network. Are you running 4.2.1? Is your AppleTV up to date?

Comment: I don't have an apple tv so it shouldn't be there at all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not **just** for AirPlay.  It's general-purpose media redirection. You can use it to switch between the built-in earpiece, the speaker on the bottom, Bluetooth earpiece, etc when on a phone call.  For example, I placed a call then went over to the audio controls in the multitasking bar.[image]

It just so happens that the *primary* use is for AirPlay and media playback.

Comment: iPhone speaker? The icon appears when I have no airplay or bluetooth devices or headphones

Comment: This was on a call, with nothing plugged in or connected via BT/AirPlay.  The "iPhone" option is for the normal earpiece and the "iPhone Speaker" option is for speakerphone use.

Comment: And the point in this is? Theres a speaker button right there in the main screen.

Comment: @Jonathan : The best reason I can think of is that when you're in another app but on a call, you can easily use this method without leaving the app. But yeah, in most cases the obvious button is the easier method.